# How to extract the element from a List of array in F#?

Tags: .net, f#

There is a list of lists in F#:

```
> wCost;;
val it : (float * float) list =
  [(0.1, 13.61972782); (1.527722646, 1.123863823); 
   (1.850460992, 0.4853361402);
   (1.923416366, 0.452707936); (1.939908012, 0.4510406634);
   (1.943635968, 0.4509554673); (1.944478676, 0.4509511138)]
```

I can retrieve the first list with index:

```
> wCost.[0];;
val it : float * float = (0.1, 13.61972782)
```

However, if I would retrieve the second element of first list, unfortunately, it is not same as I expected

```
e.g. wCost[0][0] // it cannot retrieve the second element of first list.
13.61972782
```

Please feel free to comment how to retrieve the element of list. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example `wCost` is of type `(float * float) list` which is not a list of lists, but a list of tuples. Tuples in F# don't have support for index access, so you might either want to convert the tuples to two-element lists

```
wCost
|> List.map (fun (x,y) -> [x; y])
```

or use Tuple functions to access the individual elements

```
wCost.[0] |> fst
```

and

```
wCost.[0] |> snd
```

Comment: Thank you. If I have a long series of elements, It seems I can access the elements with a Matrix-like index.

Answer (score 7):

You actually have a list of ***tuples***, rather than a list of lists.

That means when you first index the list, you return a tuple (i.e. an `int * int`) rather than a list.

To access the element, you thus use the `fst` or `snd` keyword to access the elements: see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.fst%5B't1,'t2%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D

In your case, you would write `fst (wCost.[0])` to get what you want.